# Query with date and timespan in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, hql

I want to use Hibernate to query with the condition like `where A.beginTimestamp + A.timespan > current_timestamp()`.

The `beginTimestamp` is a timestamp column and `A.timespan` is the time span in seconds.

How to do this in Hibernate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the function TIMESTAMPDIFF in the where clause from the query in your DAO. Its signature is:

TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2): Returns the integer difference between datetime_expr1 and datetime_expr2

The unit for the result is given by the unit argument.

The unit should be one of the following values:

```
FRAC_SECOND,
SECOND,
MINUTE,
HOUR,
DAY,
WEEK,
MONTH,
QUARTER, or
YEAR.
```